# Setup Emacs for Django development

Tags: python, django, emacs

I am trying to set up emacs for django development. I already have elpy, jedi and flycheck set up and working with my venvs, but when I go to look for extending my setup for django development, I find too many related modes that seem to be doing similar things.

Specifically package-list-packages gives me the following options:

- django-commands
- django-manage
- django-mode
- djangonaught
- pony-mode
- python-django

Searching the web for comparisons doesn't seem to yield much result and I can't find anything relevant or recent here. Now I can certainly try each and every one of these for a day or two and evaluate them one by one, but I was wondering if somebody can at least help me eliminate some of the options or give me some advice on the matter. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this post helps you https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/

Comment: @HigorRossato unfortunately, as I said in my question, I already have elpy, jedi, flycheck and other minor things set up and working correctly. The question is specifically about django modes and that post doesn't even mention django.

Comment: for formatting, you probably already use it, but `web-mode` supports django, and you can write snippets specifically for it with yas conditions `# condition: (string= web-mode-engine "django")`

Comment: Check out python-django. It has been working quite well for me. https://github.com/fgallina/python-django.el

Comment: 2 years on: can you please post an answer to yourself that might help other people? What did you eventually end up using?